# conditions and ranges in R like sql

Tags: r, database, grepl

This may be a simple question but how do we mimic the following sql code in R?

Like '[0-9][a-z][1-9][0-9]'

I'm assuming some version of grepl or substr but I'm unsure how.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need mimic sql code , you could directly using it in R with package `sqldf`

```
sqldf("select * from df where column like '[0-9][a-z][1-9][0-9]'")
```

Or you can try this ,

```
A=expand.grid(0:9, letters,1:9,0:9)
B=apply(A,1,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ''))
df[df$Column%in%B,]
```

Comment: I should have been clear. I want to steer clear of sqldf. Is there an implementation in data table?

Comment: @LoF10 sorry I am not using `grepl` frequently , but I provide another small trick